# Understanding Xamarin Essentials Preferences

Tags: xamarin.forms, sharedpreferences, xamarin.essentials

I have a Xamarin Forms application that is currently only targeting the Android platform. For this application, I need to store some application settings. For this, I have looked at the preferences capability of the Xamarin Essentials library.

After reading the documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)), there are a couple of things that I do not understand.

First, the section titled "Platform Implementation Specifics" (for Android) states the following:

> All data is stored into Shared Preferences. If no sharedName is
> specified the default shared preferences are used, else the name is
> used to get a private shared preferences with the specified name.

Following the link in this section, it seems that there are couple of different ways to get preferences (shared or not?). However, looking at the API for the Xamarin Essentials library, I do not see how this is done / understand the concept. Can someone elaborate on this?

Second, from reading the section titled "Integrate with System Settings", it sounds like you have the option to tie preferences into system settings. To me, this sounds like I can change a preference setting without actually being inside of the application (from the Settings *widget*). Is this correct? If so, how can I set this up from Xamarin Forms? Following the link it appears that I would need to define a settings screen. I am not sure what is required / where to place everything. Can someone elaborate on this? Can someone point me to a code sample?

Comment: if you look at the API docs, many of the Prereferences methods have an overload that allow you to specify a name for a the backing store you want to use.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.preferences?view=xamarin-essentials

Comment: for your 2nd question, there are links to sample projects in the docs.  Because these are inherently platform specific, you would not implement them in Forms, but would write them using platform APIs in the the respective platform projects.

Comment: @Jason - Regarding your second comment, are you talking about the sample located at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html? If so, I am not sure how to tie this in with the rest of the Xamarin Forms stuff. If not, I did not see any other sample code.

Comment: Xamarin provides an iOS sample, I did not realize the Android sample was a link to native code.  See this instead: https://guides.peruzal.com/xamarin-android/persistence/#adding-a-setting-screen-using-preferencefragmentcompat

Comment: @Jason - Several things. I was able to get something working in a Xamarin Android project using the link you provided. I had to use a combination of information from different sources (include the link to the Android developer documentation that I mentioned) as some of the types in the document you mentioned are marked as obsolete. I am still not sure how all of this would tie in with Xamarin forms. What I mean is that the guides created a menu in Android which seems to be the equivalent of a ToolbarItem in Xamarin Forms. How do I navigate to another activity if I use the ToolbarItem?

Comment: @Jason - At any rate, if you would like to summarize your comments in an answer I will mark it as accepted as it got me on the correct path. I am not sure how far I can take it though.

Comment: HI there, can you share if you managed this and how? Thx